# How to support both MP3 and WAV for a gstreamer source element plugin

Tags: rust, gstreamer

I'm developing a gstreamer plugin using the rust programming language. It's a source element and gets a text as a parameter and returns the correspoding speech of the text using some kinds of TTS providers(Google, Amazon, WellSaid, etc). Some providers return an MP3 file and some WAV. So what is the best approach to send the received sound file to the src pad of the element?

1. Decode MP3 and return PCM for both MP3 and WAV files. (I don't know whether it's possible to decode it inside the plugin or not)
2. Make the source dynamic to have an MP3 pad or WAV pad.

I'm new to gstreamer and I don't know which approach is better.

Answer (score 1):

Output whatever you receive and let the next elements worry about decoding. That way you're not adding unnecessary complexity to your element, and applications can decide which MP3 decoder they want to use or if they want to directly forward the MP3 elsewhere without re-encoding.

Comment: How does the next element understand the output type?

Comment: Based on the caps. The format of a stream is signalled in GStreamer via the caps inside the caps event. All buffers following that event are to be interpreted according to those caps.